# Why does TCL time command return a negative number

Tags: tcl

I am measuring the performance aspect of a certain command of an application that supports TCL as a command language. So I do the following:

```
time {COMMAND}
```

But the number returned is a negative number. What does that mean?

The example is too complicated to be included in the port.Sorry.

Comment: Specify the platform and tcl version and rough wallclock time (minutes, hours, days?). At the moment your question contains insufficient detail.

Comment: Is your platform 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, with a whale clock time of ~5h and decided to go for two calls to `clock seconds` instead, giving me correct values.

Answer (score 0):

That's *highly* unlikely. It should be producing a result like:

```
12345 microseconds per iteration
```

For a negative result, either your code is really long-lasting and you're on a build that gets wrap-around wrong (which is nothing recent, but I'm not 100% sure that some version of 8.4 didn't get it wrong), or you've had some action that sets the system clock backwards while the code is running (which might or might not be explicitly in your script). Tcl itself doesn't have anything that sets the time, and in 8.5 onwards it uses floating-point arithmetic to work out the per-iteration time.

If your output is a plain `-1`, you're simply not using the standard Tcl `time` command (which has produced those extra words for at least 20 years now).

Comment: I know that's the output of `time` because the command is documented in the old 1st edition of _Tcl and the Tk Toolkit_, and that's the book I learned Tcl from so I remember when I got my copy pretty well!